# ATtiny85 with sleep and serial

Tags: interrupt, softwareserial, attiny, sleep, attiny85

I want to communicate over serial to another device (dfplayer) and also set the microcontroller into sleep mode.

The ATtiny85 does not have a hardware serial pin so I need to use a virtual serial (like `SoftwareSerial.h`)

I've googled a lot and tried a lot of things but it basically seems to come always to the same problem. `SoftwareSerial` (or `NeoSWSerial`) do not work with `avr/sleep`. Something to do with interrupts,

> NeoSWSerial.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `NeoSWSerial::read()': (.text+0x0): multiple definition of` __vector_2'
> .pio\build\attiny85\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

AltSoftSerial won't work because it requires a 16bit timer which the ATtiny does not have__

Is there anything I can do about this?

---

What I actually want to do

Connect 6 buttons with 6 different resistors to a single ADC pin of the controller. When a button is pressed wake up the device /if necessary), read the ADC value, pick a track based on that value and then play the track on the dfplayer.

After a while, if no button is pressed, put the dfplayer and the mcu to sleep. And that's why I need the mcu at all. You can't set the dfplayer to sleep or wake it up without serial

---

Update:

I confused SPI and Serial indeed. I need to use serial communication

I want to send and receive packages. Send: `InitCommand`, Receive: `PlayerInitialized` / `InitializationFailed`. And so on.Well it's some hex codes of course but you get the point I think

My flow should basiclly look like this:

boot/wakeup  // <-- this is where I need the interrupt, don't I?
read adc value
pick track number based on adc value
send PlayTrack command to DFPlayer
delay x ms
send Sleep command to DFPlayer
go back to sleep

But the issue is in the combination of the Sleep and SoftwareSerial library. It's not the interrupt that is an issue. At least not yet

Comment: You've mentioned SPI and ADC - where does serial come into this?

Comment: The DFPlayer uses Serial.  I'm not sure where SPI is coming into this.  Perhaps the poster is confused about what SPI is.

Comment: Are you getting stuff **from** dfplayer, or sending stuff **to** it? If you are sending it to the player, I don't see where the interrupts are needed.

Comment: @NickGammon I updated my post to answer your question. Thank you

Comment: @Delta_G I updated my post to clarify the situation. Thanks

Comment: SoftwareSerial takes over all of the PCINT interrupt vectors.  That's all the pin change interrupts.  Your sleep code is wanting to use one of those interrupt vectors as well, likely as a wake signal.  The answer is going to either be modifying SoftwareSerial to only use the one vector it needs in your particular case, or finding another soft serial library that doesn't take them all.  I don't know which library would fit that bill so I'll just leave this a comment and not an answer.  Perhaps if someone knows the right library here they can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Delta_G](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/33871) I was able to figure out a solution.

I took the source files of the SoftwareSerial library [from github](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src) and copied it to my project. I renamed it so it wont give any conflicts. I then continued to comment out the interrupts in the cpp file and took care of calling `handle_interrupt` from my program. I also had to remove the inline keyword from the `handle_interrupt` function

I've posted my [modified files on github](https://gist.github.com/boop5/0cad063d281f181d31f84593eaffd12a).

Answer (score 0):

> boot/wakeup // <-- this is where I need the interrupt, don't I?

Is the interrupt to detect that you have pressed one of the buttons? If you have that then you shouldn't need to use a timer to wake up.

If you connect your buttons with resistors in such a way that any button at all will send at least 0.6Vcc (ie. 3V upwards for a 5V system) then that could be configured to generate an interrupt (a rising interrupt). So you might set up the resistors so the buttons send 3.2V, 3.5V, 3.8V, 4.1V, 4.4V and 4.7V. That gives you six different voltages and they are all high enough to be considered "high" on a digital pin. Then make that pin generate the interrupt and also do the ADC reading on it once you wake up.

Then you can put the processor into a deep sleep until a button is pressed. While the track is playing you might also set up a watchdog timer interrupt so that you can wake up and check if it is time to put the player to sleep as well.