# How to properly read ADC on an ATtiny85?

Tags: adc, attiny85, digital-analog-conversion

**What I want to do**: attach six buttons to a single input. Each button triggers a different action.

**How I want to do it**: Use an AD conversion and add a resistor with different values to each button so that you can distinguish between the different input signals
I use these values: 1k, 4.7k, 18k, 22k, 55k, 300k

Vcc is stable 3.3v but I also tried it on 5v. I use Vcc as reference value for the ADC.

**The problem I have**: no matter what I do I always read the same value on the ADC. Connected to  GND it reads 0 and on Vcc it reads a value that’s always the same regardless what resistor I actually use.

I tried a lot of things I’ve found on the internet but nothing really worked for me. I’m clearly doing something wrong

This is the method I call in `setup()` to initialize the converter on ADC2(pb4)

```
void initADC()
{
  // 8-bit resolution
  // set ADLAR to 1 to enable the Left-shift result (only bits ADC9..ADC2 are available)
  // then, only reading ADCH is sufficient for 8-bit results (256 values)

  ADMUX =
            (1 << ADLAR) |     // left shift result
            (0 << REFS1) |     // Sets ref. voltage to VCC, bit 1
            (0 << REFS0) |     // Sets ref. voltage to VCC, bit 0
            (0 << MUX3)  |     // use ADC2 for input (PB4), MUX bit 3
            (0 << MUX2)  |     // use ADC2 for input (PB4), MUX bit 2
            (1 << MUX1)  |     // use ADC2 for input (PB4), MUX bit 1
            (0 << MUX0);       // use ADC2 for input (PB4), MUX bit 0

  ADCSRA = 
            (1 << ADEN)  |     // Enable ADC 
            (1 << ADPS2) |     // set prescaler to 64, bit 2 
            (1 << ADPS1) |     // set prescaler to 64, bit 1 
            (0 << ADPS0);      // set prescaler to 64, bit 0  
}
```

The code is taken from here https://www.marcelpost.com/wiki/index.php/ATtiny85_ADC

The page seems to be down at the moment so here is an archived version of it
https://web.archive.org/web/20230128091128/https://www.marcelpost.com/wiki/index.php/ATtiny85_ADC

In the `loop()` method I do basically this: Read ADC and then blink an LED *n* times, based on the read value.

```
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);         // start ADC measurement
while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC) ); // wait till conversion complete 

uint8_t adcValue = ADCH;

if (adcValue >= 0 && adcValue < 32) {
  blink(1);
} else if (adcValue >= 32 && adcValue < 126) {
  blink(2);
} else if (adcValue >= 126 && adcValue < 193) {
  blink(3);
} else if (adcValue >= 193 && adcValue < 227) {
  blink(4);
} else if (adcValue >= 227 && adcValue < 245) {
  blink(5);
} else if (adcValue >= 245 && adcValue <= 255) {
  blink(6);
}
delay(60000);
```

My breadboard has the resistors going from Vcc to an empty row and I connect a jumperwire from PB4 to one of these resistors and do an external reset of the microcontroller to test my setup. They share GND/Vcc

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to *debug* this?

Thanks

Comment: you forgot to connect a resistor between analog input and ground ... research voltage divider

Comment: Are you using an Arduino core which does not support `analogRead()` or is there another reason why you are directly reading ADC registers ? The ADC is 10bit  so can read analog values up to 1023. Does your application allow for pressing two or more buttons simultaneously? If you have a multimeter you could check the voltage between the analog pin and ground when a button is pressed.

Comment: Funnily enough, [someone else](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/93902/attiny85-with-sleep-and-serial/93913#93913) also wanted to connect six buttons to an ATtiny85 to "Connect 6 buttons with 6 different resistors to a single ADC pin of the controller". It's an amazing coincidence!

Comment: @NickGammon I unfortunately can’t tell if you’re trying to be funny or sarcastic. It’s the same project but a different question.

Comment: Adding a schematic to your question, showing at least everything connected to the A/D pin, would help!

Comment: "I unfortunately can’t tell if you’re trying to be funny or sarcastic . . . ". This does not help. Please focus your efforts on providing responses to the followup questions you have been asked and are, as yet, unanswered. It is, incidentally, in the nature of school assignments that multiple instances of the same question can appear in various guises.

Comment: @6v6gt It wasn't my intention to be sassy. I was just confused by nicks comment so I tried to explain me

Comment: there is no schematic diagram in the question ... it is impossible to determine how the OP connected everything ... voting to close for being unclear

Comment: TBH I was indeed wondering if it was an assignment. Also maybe the previous question about the same thing may have helped, so it was a pointer to check it out.

Comment: @NickGammon I guess this is going too far here but it's meant to become a toy for my daughter. Not an assignment

Comment: OK, sorry for doubting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [@jsotola](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/40318) only posted their solution as a comment. But it was the correct answer. So I'll just post my solution here

I now use a voltage divider setup with these values:

Voltage divider formula `Vs * R2 / (R1 + R2)`

Vs: 3.3v
R2: 100k Ohm
R1: 10k (3.0v), 27k (2.8v), 38k (2.6v), 50k (2.2v), 65k (2.0v)

Using an 8-bit ADC, I came up with these *if* statements to distinguish between the inputs. I gave it some room for deviation

```
if (adcValue >= 227 && adcValue <= 237)
{
  // 10k ohm (3.0V -> adc 232)
}
else if (adcValue >= 212 && adcValue <= 223)
{
  // 18k ohm (2.8V -> adc 217)
}
else if (adcValue >= 196 && adcValue <= 206)
{
  // 27k ohm (2.6V -> adc 201)
}
else if (adcValue >= 181 && adcValue <= 191)
{
  // 38k ohm (2.4V -> adc 186)
}
else if (adcValue >= 165 && adcValue <= 175)
{
  // 50k ohm (2.2V -> adc 170)
}
else if (adcValue >= 150 && adcValue <= 160)
{
  // 65k ohm (2.0V -> adc 155)
}
```

Here is a picture of my breadboard. I know it's not a real schematic but I couldn't figure that out right now. But I hope it's good enough

[image]

Comment: a comment is the only thing that was appropriate ... only a guess could be provided because of lack of information in the question

Comment: I don't see six buttons here. Is this a work in progress?

Comment: @NickGammon I just inserted different resistors to test each of them one by one. That was easier than setting up 6 buttons and was good enough. Just needed to know if it works in general

Comment: There seem to be some gaps in your ranges. For example, what if adcValue is 238? But perhaps that is deliberate. You could probably rewrite as only doing greater-than tests. For example, >= 227, then if it fails that, >= 212 and so on. Testing the other limit seems redundant.

Comment: It is not clear if it matters in this use case but a 65k resistor in parallel with a 50k resistor is effectively a 28.2k resistor. This is very close, allowing for tolerances, to the 27k resistor you are also using meaning that it could be difficult to distinguish between a single button press and at least some combinations of multiple button presses.